# How to Pass Argument to constructor dynamically using structureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

please note that this is my first project with DI and IoC thank you for all your help.

I am creating a multitenant app, were the application db context change from one tenant to another by providing a dynamic connection string.

while initialize the controllers and providing the connection string to the DAL class i am getting "String connectionString = Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined"

DbContext:

```
public partial class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
    // rest of the code ....
}
```

DAL:

```
public class ManagerDAL : IEntityRepository<TestManager>
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public ManagerDAL(string connectionString)
    {
        _context = new DataContext(connectionString);
    }
    // rest of the code
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController
{
    private ManagerDAL _managerDAL;
    // .... different DAL

    public TestController()
    {
        _managerDAL = new ManagerDAL("ConnectionString");
    }
    // reset of the code
}
```

Please any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhanaid/introduction-to-structure-map/ check this article

Comment: i suggest you to read that article and try out something, then if you face any issue with implementing the DI post that as a question.

Comment: @sriram i did go through alot of tutorials on DI and Structure map thanks for your contribution, this is for an older version of structure map where ObjectFactory was still in use.this wont work my current application

Comment: man its better you try out what you understand and if you come across any issue post that as a question instead asking for implementation.